# React Table removes Filters when updating data

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am using the material ui kitchen sink example of react table (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/material-UI-kitchen-sink)

My data updates frequently, the issue is, that the filters are cleared everytime I update the data. You can try this by setting a filter in the codesandbox example and changing a value in a cell. onBlur it sets the state and with that the filters are cleared and checkboxes are unchecked.

Is there a way to prevent that or a solution/workaround for it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: filters is included in the react-table package so when you update data the component reload the filters values.
what you need to do is put a filters outside of the plugin and you can keep the values out there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set auto reset flag for global filters to `false` -

```
autoResetGlobalFilter: false
```

Fixed CSB - https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-oskar-sqefh?file=/src/components/EnhancedTable.js:3191-3226

More details - https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useGlobalFilter#table-options

Comment: Thank you! Solved

Comment: Solved my problem with autoResetFilters:false

Answer (score 0):

Add `autoResetAll: false` into your useReactTable options
`const table = useReactTable({ autoResetAll: false })`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While it's documented [here](https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/api/core/table#autoresetall), this options doesn't seem to do anything in my project when set to false. Setting the other `autoReset*` options do work so I've just got a big list of them in my parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think in react-table (v7.7.0), you can avoid unexpected results in filters by adding `autoResetFilters: false` to `useTable` hook, (and also avoid unexpected results in sorting and pagination by adding `autoResetPage: false`, and `autoResetSortBy: false` to `useTable` hook) like so:

```js
const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
        autoResetPage: false,
        autoResetFilters: false,
        autoResetSortBy: false
    }, usePagination)
```

You can also add `autoResetAll: false` instead of those three lines of code.